# Show that the limit of $ f(x)$ as $x\rightarrow 0$ is $0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Show directly from the definition of a limit of a function that

```
lim x->0 (x^(1/3) * sin(1/x)) = 0.
```

The definition is

The limit of f as x goes to p is q if for every e>0 there exists a d>0

s.t.

```
dx(x,p)<d for x belongs to E -> dy(f(x), q)< e
```

with the notation

```
limi x->p f(x) = q
```

My approach

We want to show that

```
dx(x,0)<d, x belongs to E -> dy( (x^(1/3) * sin(1/x)),0) < e
```

which is

```
| x-0| < d - > | x |<d
```

and

```
|(x^(1/3) * sin(1/x))|< e
```

Now the solution I have takes e^3=d and shows that

```
|(x^(1/3) * sin(1/x))|< d^(1/3)=e
```

which makes no sense...

I suppose the steps start from

```
|x^(1/3)|<= d^(1/3)

|x^(1/3)| * | sin(1/x)|<= d^(1/3) * | 1| (Does he multiply by one because the max value of sin is 1 and hence it will always be smaller? )
```

Then takes

```
e^3=d
```

and somehow it is proven. It makes much more sense that I explained it now but I am looking to see what people think....

Please edit the notation if you know how. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site.  This is a very well written question overall, but you might want to read [this meta thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/13800/5531).  Use of "urgent" can trigger bad feelings for some of us :)

Comment: Maybe you can use L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: I think you proof is good. Very standard.

Comment: @AntonioVargas I have an exam in 9 hours, sorry if it is misleading but it is really urgent for me :)

Comment: @John Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to show that for every positive $\epsilon$, there is a positive $\delta$ such that 
$$\left|x^{1/3}\sin(1/x)-0\right|\lt \epsilon\quad\text{whenever}\quad 0\lt |x-0|\lt \delta. \tag{1}$$

So let $\epsilon\gt 0$ be given. Note that if $x\ne 0$ then 
$$\left|x^{1/3}\sin(1/x)-0\right|\le |x|^{1/3},\tag{1}$$
since $|\sin(1/x)|\le 1$.

If $|x|\lt \epsilon^3$, then $|x|^{1/3}\lt \epsilon$. Let $\delta=\epsilon^3$. Then whenever $0\lt |x|\lt \delta$, by (2) we will have $\left|x^{1/3}\sin(1/x)-0\right|\lt \epsilon$. We have shown that for every $\epsilon\gt 0$, there is a $\delta\gt 0$ such that (1) holds. This completes the proof.

Comment: Please if you can also help me out with this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835723/show-that-the-sequence-converges-to-0