# Show that the set of 2 continuous functions is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ and $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be continuous functions. Show the set $ E = \{ x \in\mathbb R: f(x)=g(x)\} $ is closed.

**My approach**

A solution I found is the following:

$h=f-g$

$h(x)=f(x)-g(x)=0$

f and g are continious and h is continious

Taking $h(E)=\{ x\in \mathbb R:h(x)=0\}$ // makes no sense, why $x\in\mathbb R$ and not $h(x)\in\mathbb R$

$h^{-1} (E)=\{0\}$ is closed  // why is the inverse only zero?

=> $E$ is closed

Is the solution correct? Seems very elegant and short, but $h(E)$ makes no sense to me please explain.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want $h^{-1}(0)$, not $h^{-1}(E)$. A single point is a closed , set, so the inverse image is...

Comment: No, $h(E)$ is not equal to $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : h(x) = 0\}$; rather, $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : h(x) = 0\} = h^{-1}(E)$. In fact, $h(E) = \{0\}$.

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144480/show-that-the-set-x-in-a-b-fx-gx-is-closed-in-bbb-r) and other questions shown there among linked questions.

Answer (score 3):

How much do you know about continuous functions? For example, do you know that for a continuous function $h$ and a closed set $X$, the set $h^{-1}(X)$ is always closed?

---

If you know that, the continuation is badly written, but captures the idea. First, you define the function $h = f-g$. Then, you can see that $$E=\{x\in \mathbb R: f(x) = g(x)\} = \{x\in\mathbb R: f(x)-g(x)=0\} = \{x\in\mathbb R: h(x) = 0\} = h^{-1}(\{0\})$$

This means that $E$ is the preimage of $\{0\}$ for the function $h$, and, since $h$ is continuous and $\{0\}$ is a closed set, $E$ is a closed set.

Comment: it is known that f is cont E subset of X is closed than f^-1 (E) is closed.

Comment: @user2253741 If you know that, than the second part of my question should explain everything.

Comment: can you please answer the 2 questions I asked explicitly. I still have hard time understanding.

Comment: @user2253741 Rather than understanding what you wrote (which is at best confuzing and actually quite wrong, since $h^{-1}(E)$ is not $\{0\}$), take a look at my answer (which is probably what your answer tried, but failed to, be.

Comment: can you explain what is the deal with the inverse of the function of the set? I find it hard to understand. h−1({0}), also what is the deal with the {0} set I didn't understand your explanation maybe you could use some reference.

Comment: $h^{-1}(A)$ is not the inverse function of $h$, it is the preimage of the set $A$. By definition, $h^{-1}(A) = \{x\in X, h(x) \in A\}$.